# Android-Studio: How to enable "Create field for parameter" after Alt+Enter

Tags: android-studio

I accidently clicked on "Disable Create field for parameter..." after Alt+Enter, go to "Create field for paramter..."

How can I enable that Autogeneration feature to have the option back?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Editor -> Intentions and tick accidently disabled field.